# how to use firewalld in stateful mode

Tags: centos, firewall, firewalld, centos8

I have to setup an stateful firewall on centos8 using firewalld.
I'm new to firewalld but have experience with old style iptables for this purpose.
since it is recommended by Redhat [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/using-and-configuring-firewalld_configuring-and-managing-networking#when-to-use-firewalld-nftables-or-iptables_getting-started-with-firewalld) I prefer to not combine two methods like firewalld and iptables. 
I want to know is there a way to use firewalld in stateful mode? if it is how?

thank you

Comment: @A.B No I didn't. would you please explain more? or share any link for this? I couldn't find anything about that.

Comment: I've already checked that, didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to [setenforce 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/166073/setenforce-1) and his excellent answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/679208/502766).

Firewalld configures iptables or nftables, and the resulting configuration is stateful (based on connstate status: established, related, untrack, invalid, new).

You can check the actual configuration with `iptables -L -n -v` and `nft list ruleset`.

You can choose which backend you want to use in `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf` with the option `FirewallBackend`. If you want Firewalld to use iptables, you have to set: `FirewallBackend=iptables`

If you want to disable Firewalld to use you standard iptables configurations, you can use:

```sh
systemctl disable firewalld --now
systemctl mask firewalld
```

hope it helps for others.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer suggests a workable solution to the question is available via another website. The Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites [generally frowns on this type of answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers), even when the link is to another SE site. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising your answer to include the steps required to resolve the issue.